Unable to connect Yamaha P-35B to iPad?
I bought one of these dongles https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08D6YG8GH?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details in order to connect my Yamaha P-35B (no computer port, only has the 5-pin MIDI ports) to my iPad Air with a USB-C port. When I plugged it in, I discovered that nothing showed up on the iPad... not even an "accessory not recognized". The same behavior is happening with my Mac, so I'm guessing it's probably an issue with the piano or MIDI interface, rather than the iPad.
Any guesses what else I could try? I'm considering buying a new keyboard with a proper USB-computer port, or trying out a new MIDI interface...

It sounds a lot like the dongle is broken. I would start with requesting a replacement, and if that does not work, switching to different adapter.
